# Redirect subdomain to https site

Tags: apache-virtualhost

I'm trying to redirect bot.domain.tld to https://domain.tld:8087, but it only redirect the domain to http://domain.tld:8087.
The port is only reachable with https so it doesn't work if it doesn't redirect correctly.

Entry in the apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName bot.domain.tld
  RedirectPermanent / https://domain.tld:8087/
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit: It seems to work on some web browsers, but firefox (on mac) still redirect me to the http site, while firefox on windows & safari redirect me to https ._.

Comment: If it works on some browsers but not others, there might be an old version of the page stored in the browser's cache, or in a caching proxy that's used by the non-redirecting browser. That problem should be fixable by flushing the cache.

Comment: what happens if you use firefox on mac and type in the wanted https: url directly ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you examined the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html)? There are several examples using the [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) tool with conditionals etc. You may also want to take a look at [what not to use mod_rewrite for](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html) as well.

Example from the manual:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect "/" "https://www.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The code still DOESNT redirect to the HTTPS site. :/